# Android: how to create per-item settings activity?

Tags: android, listview, settings

I have a collection of items which are shown using a ListView.
Each of these items has its own settings. By clicking on one item I want to allow the user to view/change its settings.

What is the best way to do this?

It would be nice if I could use something like [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) as this provides a nice layout. Unfortunately the preference mechanism always saves the chosen preferences to a global file (see [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)).

A workaround might be using multiple files, one per item, but I don't like this solution since the collection is dynamic and I prefer the settings to be local to my objects.

Another workaround might be opening a PreferenceActivity, then reading all the settings and saving them to the appropriate object. This also seems far from elegant.

Finally, I could implement my own activity with a ListView and custom item layouts, but this seems a duplicated work to get the same behavior and style.

Any suggestion is welcome :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something along the lines of PreferenceActivity, but save the preferences to the items themselves or something associated with them. To display the preferences input, use a dialog Fragment. You can then either pop up the dialog, or display it as a regular Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
That's basically the latest option: implementing my own ListView item layouts. That's what I'm currently doing but I would prefer a more elegant way.